# JS cant find out how to code multiple options in form so there will be different outcomes

Tags: javascript, forms, html-select

For a school assignment I have to create a form with 4 options of exchange rates. But I cant really find out how to calculate this. I have tried alot of different things but they all didnt give me the outcome i wanted.

this is the code I have so far

```js
function euro_dollarkoers() {
  return (1.36);
}

function dollar_eurokoers() {
  return (0.74);
}

function euro_rublekoers() {
  return (48.40);
}

function ruble_eurokoers() {
  return (0.02);
}

function dollar_naar_euro(dollars) {
  return (dollars * dollar_eurokoers());
}

function euro_naar_dollar(euro) {
  return (euro * euro_dollarkoers());
}

function exchange() {
  if (document.getElementById('dollar/euro').selected == True) {
    dollar_naar_euro(document.form.bedrag.value).toFixed(2);
  } else if (document.getElementById('euro/dollar').selected == True) {
    euro_naar_dollar(document.form.bedrag.value).toFixed(2);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Lab 10</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="lab10.js"></script>

  <form name="form">
    <input type="text" name="bedrag" placeholder="Vul bedrag in">
    <select name="koersen">
      <option value="dollar/euro">dollar/euro</option>
      <option value="euro/dollar">euro/dollar</option>
      <option value="ruble/euro">ruble/euro</option>
      <option value="euro/ruble">euro/ruble</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" name="conversie" value="converteren" onclick="document.write('Conversie: ' + dollar_naar_euro(document.form.bedrag.value).toFixed(2))">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: First of all, you could close your `select` tag. The `return` statements don't need `()`. For example: `function euro_dollarkoers () { return 1.36; }`. What is the expected result and what result do you get?

Comment: `but they all didnt give me the outcome i wanted.` - Can you list the **expected** results and **actual** results please? - I formatted your code and added the closing `select` and `form` tag as that is not the cause of the issue and most likely a copy/paste error, however, feel free to remove it again if that is indeed how you have the code.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many mistakes in your logic, e.g.

- using `value` property as `id` value
- using document.write

You need to simplify your logic to

```
var functions = {
  "euro/dollar": 1.36,
  "dollar/euro": 0.74,
  "euro/ruble" : 48.40,
  "ruble/euro": 0.02
};

function exchange() {
  var optValue = document.getElementById( "koersen" ).value;
  var currValue = +document.getElementById( "bedrag" ).value;
  console.log( ( functions[optValue] * currValue ).toFixed(2) );
}
```

```js
var functions = {
  "euro/dollar": 1.36,
  "dollar/euro": 0.74,
  "euro/ruble" : 48.40,
  "ruble/euro": 0.02
};

function exchange() {
  var optValue = document.getElementById( "koersen" ).value;
  var currValue = +document.getElementById( "bedrag" ).value;
  console.log( ( functions[optValue] * currValue ).toFixed(2) );
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="bedrag" placeholder="Vul bedrag in">
<select id="koersen">
    <option value = "dollar/euro">dollar/euro</option>
    <option value = "euro/dollar">euro/dollar</option>
    <option value = "ruble/euro">ruble/euro</option>
    <option value = "euro/ruble">euro/ruble</option>
</select>
<input type="button" name="conversie" value="converteren" onclick="exchange()">
```